# Using SpaceEvenly in row inside ListView won't work

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use a horizontal list view in flutter which will contain a custom widget.
I want each item have space to his left and right, I tried using 'SpaceEvenly' but it won't effect anything.

This is my widget which will be the list view item:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FriendWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FriendWidgetState createState() => _FriendWidgetState();
}

class _FriendWidgetState extends State<FriendWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30.0,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/portrait_placeholder.jpg'),
          ),
          Text(
            'Name',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my ListView:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'FriendWidget.dart';

class FriendsSecion extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 2),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        height: 100,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FriendWidget(),
                  FriendWidget(),
                  FriendWidget(),
                  FriendWidget(),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how it looks now: I'm trying to have a space between each item that has avatar and 'name' text.
[image]

Comment: Can you share a picture of what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Darshan Sure, I uploaded it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom `width` to your `FriendWidget` class to justify the `spaceEvenly` property in the Row. Sample code snippet:

```
class _FriendWidgetState extends State<FriendWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      child: Column(

        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
                   ...
```

[image]

I also noticed that if you comment `scrollDirection` property, the custom widget automatically aligns themselves to `spaceEvenly`, (need to explore why this happens) but since you need horizontal scroll, adding a custom width to your widgets will make them `spaceEvenly` and after adding more custom widgets, it scrolls horizontally properly.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much!